# Can I a POST below code to any othes domain?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors, xmlhttprequest, same-origin-policy

Is it possible to make an HTTP POST request from JavaScript to any 
   domain name?

**Javascript**

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("POST", 'URL linki', true);

 //Send the proper header information along with the request

 xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { // Call a function when the state changes.

if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 200) {

    // Request finished. Do processing here.

 }
 }
 xhr.send("foo=bar&lorem=ipsum");

 // xhr.send(new Int8Array());

 // xhr.send(document);
```

and  I would like print on the screen. Is it possible?

Comment: yes, as long as a) it accepts it, b) it understands it, and c) if you want a response the server allows CORS

Comment: You can, but you might not :)

Comment: why I cannot, can you explain more pls

Comment: All you need is here: http://www.ajax-cross-origin.com/how.html

Comment: tnx so much , ı understand very well  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to make a request to any domain as long as the domain in question accepts the request, and the server allows CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing). The latter is only required if you want a response, as you're sharing resources across origins.